# serializer.save() not saving in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am having a problem with my APIView for reading and writing names of places. Here is my view,

```
class pList(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        e = placename.objects.all()
        ser = placeSerializer(e,many=True)
        return Response(ser.data)

    def post(self,request):
        serializer = placeSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and my serializer

```
class placeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = placename
        fields = ('em_name')
```

the get method works fine but when i try to POST, i get an empty set([]).What am i doing wrong here?

PS: I am new to DRF.

Comment: can you show the data you are posting? and also the type of field em_name is, and the stacktrace

Comment: You might need to add a comma to make fields a tuple: `fields = ('em_name',)`

Comment: @Exprator , i corrected it just now, when i removed  many=True from the post method, it is working fine. i think , it may be because i am sending only one value!

Comment: @ikkuh , yup , corrected that.

Comment: @p.ry because you also have `many=True` in your serializer.